# Preventing a database from rejecting user input

Tags: php, escaping, adodb

I'm making a simple interface that will allow a user to modify pieces of CSS and HTML which are stored in a Microsoft SQL database. This interface uses PHP5 and ADOdb.

For some reason this form will reject any input which contains one or more single quotes. This string, for example, is not allowed: "background-image:url('paper.gif');"

I suspect ADOdb may be filtering single quotes aggressively to prevent SQL injection attacks. Is there a way to escape user input in PHP to allow for the single quote character to be stored?

I've considered automatically converting all single quotes to double quotes, but it seems like that has the potential to break the user's markup.

It's probably not very helpful, but here's an example of the test I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Edit website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CSS Test</h1>

<?php
    include_once ('database.php');
    $table = "[User Site]";

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['dbname'])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $dbname = $_REQUEST['dbname'];
        $db = Database::singleton($dbname);

        //Push any new CSS to the database
        if (isset($_POST['css'])) {
            $css = $_POST['css'];
            $sql = "UPDATE " . $table . 
                    " SET html='" . $html . "', css='" . $css . "' " .
                    " WHERE dbnameId='" . $dbname . "'";
            $db->Execute($sql);
        }

        //Fetch any CSS from the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE dbnameId='" . $dbname . "'";
        $data = recordToArray($db->Execute($sql));
        echo "<p>";
        $css = $data[0]['css'];
    }

    $rows = 20;
    $cols = 80;
?>
<!-- Show the user a form -->
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    CSS:<br>  <textarea rows="<?php echo $rows ?>" cols="<?php echo $cols ?>" name="css"><?php echo $css ?></textarea><p>
    <input type="hidden" name="dbname" value="<?php echo $dbname ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update CSS" />
</form>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using ADODB, yet you aren't using the prime feature of almost every single database abstraction library that has ever existed: placeholders / prepared statements.

Your queries are failing because things aren't being properly escaped.  Using placeholders adds escaping automatically.  Read up on [the Param method](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#param), which will insert the right type of placeholder for the database you're using.  (It looks like you're using MSSQL, and I have no idea whether it uses `?` as a placeholder or not.)

Instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE dbnameId='" . $dbname . "'";
$sth = $db->Execute($sql);
```

You want something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE dbnameId = " . $db->Param('dbname');
$psh = $db->Prepare($sql);
$sth = $db->Execute($psh, array( $dbname ));
```

(This is untested and may be subtly wrong, please read the linked manual page for a little more information.  Have I mentioned that ADODB is awful?)

Please keep in mind that ADODB is *awful* and was designed in the PHP4 era.  Please consider using something more modern, like [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: +1 for actually knowing the library (instead of Googling parameter binding for it like I did xD) and recommending a better alternative :)

Comment: I've never touched ADODB in my life, I googled for the parameter binding method as well.  I'd actually prefer your solution, as I don't really care for having to do a separate prepare.  Cross +1'd.  ;)

Comment: I'd assumed that ADODB was escaping things automatically regardless of the method used to build the statement. It's *magic!* (tm). Thanks for setting me straight; I'm using binding and switching things over to PDO now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not aggressive filtering to prevent SQL injection; it's that there's *no SQL injection prevention whatsoever* here. The single quote in the CSS is being interpreted as a single quote in the query, causing a syntax error.

I haven't used ADOdb before, but it looks like [it supports parameter binding](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#execute), which will allow you to form prettier-looking queries and have them work as expected (with no risk of SQL injection).

```
$db->Execute('UPDATE foo SET bar = ?, baz = ?', array("it's", "working"));
```

As the database sees it, the above is equivalent to the following:

```
$db->Execute("UPDATE foo SET bar = 'it\'s', baz = 'working'");
```

The syntax is correct, you avoid errors and injection, and it's much nicer to work with, anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is way easier: You are inserting the user input directly, therefore the `'` break your SQL query. (This *is* already a SQL injection!) So you need to escape those. But I don't know which method ADOdb provides for this. It's `mysql_real_escape_string` for `mysql_` and `PDO::quote` for `PDO`.

Furthermore: *Please* don't use `$_REQUEST`, use `$_POST` instead. And even ***more please*** don't use `register_globals`, it's insecure! Use `$_POST` instead.

Comment: I'm using $_REQUEST in this instance because it's easier to test. :-)